# Convert ListView into XML file(Using DOM or any other?)

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I already understood how to convert static xml file from the RES folder into ListActivity with Items.(Using DOM).

is there a way to reverse the process? iterate on each Item of the List and create XML file using DOM?

or do I have to implement it manually? thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XML CREATOR for this purpose.!